# TeamCity deletes files in working directory

Tags: teamcity

We are using Teamcity 10.0 for c++ projects.

We have 150 build configurations using linux agent and nearly 60 build configurations using windows agent.

Our server-side cleanup setting is disabled.

Project clean-up rules are `Everything is kept forever` and `Prevent dependency artifacts cleanup`

On agent side (both on linux and windows) we set `teamcity.agent.build.checkoutDir.expireHours=never` value in `buildAgent.properties` file.

Despite this settings teamcity cleans up the checkout directory periodically.(Aprox. every 5 days)

What should I do to make TC keep my files?

Answer (score 0):

Since the default value of the property checkoutDir.expireHours is 8 days and not the 5 days you are talking, you seems to have something which is overriding your value somewhere, or, a typo inside the configuration file which doesn't take into account your value.

You need to restart the agent service after setting the property.

You also might have some Build features like `Swabra` which clean-up your directory, or a `Free Disk Space` feature which is deleting checkout directories.

The Free Disk Space feature seems to be used somewhere inside your configurations.